# Selecting a modern bitmap animation approach

Tags: .net, winapi, bitmap, directx

I have a scientific research application, and need to continuously redraw a generated large (800x800 to 1200x1200) color bitmap at 10 fps or better (20 fps would be sweet) on a modern generally available PC. The bitmap represents the internal state of a process, and is generated on the fly from data in memory. I tried a naive method of drawing a .NET `Bitmap` on a `Graphics`, but this gives me 2-3 fps at best, so it did not fit the bill.

Primarily I am using .NET, and can also use any Win32 API. I did not program any graphic-intensive applications since probably DirectDraw days, and need help selecting a modern approach to do what I need.

One idea that I entertain is using a DirectShow render graph with a custom video source. But I should admit that this is perhaps the only way I know of doing fluent animation, and it is prompted by my rusty 10-year old technology knowledge.

What I am asking for is a survey of modern APIs for fast color bitmap drawing, that are accessible to a .NET/Win32 programmer, and are supported by off-the-shelf display hardware. Not only runtime speed, but also the implementation effort is important, since this is a one-off application. I am targeting Windows 7.

Comment: Direct2D is probably your best bet, if you google "direct2d .net" you'll find someone has some .NET wrappers for it which sound like they make it easier to use from managed code.

Comment: You can use DirectX (3D/2D) or OpenGL to draw the finished image. But have you thought about GENERATING the image by DirectX ?? This would maybe be faster and the displaying problem would be avoided...

Comment: @theCNG27: I do not understand exactly what do you mean by generating the image in DirectX. What I have is a matrix of double numbers, and a display function: double -> RGB pixel value. Do you think of moving the mapping part into the GPU? I am not sure this would help much in terms of speed, but looks much more complex to me. Also, I do not see how the "display problem" would be avoided if I still need the image displayed on way or the other.

Comment: Okay, then I misunderstood you. But you can still modify your display function, so that it writes those RGB values directly into a DX 2D Texture and render it.

Comment: @theCNG27: Interesting, thanks.